# .NET 8.0 does not show up in target framework after installing .NET 8 SDK

Tags: .net, sdk, visual-studio-2022, .net-8.0

I've the latest version of VS2022 version 17.8.4.

I've installed, without errors, the .NET 8.0 SDK (not the preview version).

In the Visual Studio installer, under individual components, the box next to .NET 8.0 Runtime (Long Term Support) is checked.

The Microsoft .NET SDK 8.0.101 (x64) shows up as installed in the Apps & Features (in Windows 10, build 19045.3930).

From the command line:  dotnet --list-sdks shows all the SDKS installed with 8.0.101 at the bottom.

The problem is that, in the Target Framework (for any project type - I've tried several: Blazor, Desktop, Console, etc), there is no dropdown available for .Net 8.0.

There is, however, an option to select it when creating a NEW application is made available.

On the output of dotnet --list-sdks , there is one thing to note:
The last entry, 8.0.101, has a path that is on the D: drive.

[D:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

The others are all on the C: drive.

So it appears that VS has a problem of where to look for the SDK.

Any idea on how to remedy this bug?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it a work around for this problem. When Visual Studio is installed on anything other than drive C:\ this problem occurs.

In my case, I copied the SDK folder *D:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.101*  to *C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk* folder.

I also copied the manifest over:
*D:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests\8.0.101* folder to *C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk-manifests* folder

Now it shows up in VS2022.